# Laravel unique validation on multiple columns with cast as date column

Tags: laravel, validation, request, rules

beginner to laravel here

how to cast as date the created_at column?

```php
public function rules(){
  return [
    'name' => 'required|unique:table,name,'.$this->get('id').',id,created_at,'.$this->get('created_at')
      ];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of your validation rule? The current rule reads "Unique in table named `table` using column `name`, ignoring `$this->get('id')` (using `id` as the ID column), and where `created_at` is equal to `$this->get('created_at'`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am inserting a unique name per day.